# A DRY approach to Python try-except blocks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

**Objective:** I have several lines of code each capable of producing the same type of error, and warranting the same kind of response. How do I prevent a 'do not repeat yourself' problem with the try-except blocks.

**Background:**

I using ReGex to scrape poorly formatted data from a text file, and input it into the field of a custom object. The code works great except when the field has been left blank in which case it throws an error.

I handle this error in a try-except block. If error, insert a blank into the field of the object (i.e. '').

The problem is it turns easily readable, nice, Python code into a mess of try-except blocks that each do exact same thing. This is a 'do not repeat yourself' (a.k.a. DRY) violation.

**The Code:**

*Before:*

```
sample.thickness = find_field('Thickness', sample_datum)[0]
sample.max_tension = find_field('Maximum Load', sample_datum)[0]
sample.max_length = find_field('Maximum Extension', sample_datum)[0]
sample.test_type = sample_test
```

*After:*

```
try:
    sample.thickness = find_field('Thickness', sample_datum)[0]
except:
    sample.thickness = ''

try:
    sample.max_tension = find_field('Maximum Load', sample_datum)[0]
except:
    sample.max_tension = ''

try:
    sample.max_length = find_field('Maximum Extension', sample_datum)[0]
except: 
    sample.max_length = ''

try:    
    sample.test_type = sample_test
except:
    sample.test_type = ''
```

**What I Need:**

Is there some Pythonic way to write this? Some block where I can say if there is an index-out-of-range error on any of these lines (indicating the field was blank, and ReGex failed to return anything) insert a blank in the sample field.

Comment: What kind of error does it throw?

Comment: An out of index. The find field function returns a list of the ReGex search results. If ReGex doesn't find anything, then the list it returns is empty. When I try to nab the first result I get that exception.

Comment: Come to think about it, the answer to this particular problem is trivial. Modify the `find_field()` function to return a blank on a failed ReGex search; however, I have had similar programming problems before thus the answer to this question remains relevant to others.

Comment: Just curious: What is ReGex? Seems like an awfully terrible name since it's so ungoogleable.

Comment: RegEx regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about extracting a function out of it?

```
def maybe_find_field(name, datum):
    try:
        return find_field(name, datum)[0]
    except IndexError: # Example of specific exception to catch
        return ''

sample.thickness = maybe_find_field('Thickness', sample_datum)
sample.max_tension = maybe_find_field('Maximum Load', sample_datum)
sample.max_length = maybe_find_field('Maximum Extension', sample_datum)
sample.test_type = sample_test
```

BTW, don't simply catch all possible exceptions with `except:` unless that's really what you want to do. Catching everything may hide implementation errors and become quite difficult to debug later. Whenever possible, bind your `except` case to the specific exception that you need.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite matching the question, but Google sent me here and so others might come.

I have `post` functions in two separate Django-views, which call similar backend-functions and require the same exception-handling.

I solved the issue by extracting the whole `except:`-tree and sticking it into a decorator.

Before:

```
# twice this
def post(request):
    try:
        return backend_function(request.post)
    except ProblemA as e:
        return Response("Problem A has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
    except ProblemB as e:
        return Response("Problem B has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
    except ProblemC as e:
        return Response("Problem C has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
    except ProblemD as e:
        return Response("Problem D has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
```

After:

```
# once this
def catch_all_those_pesky_exceptions(original_function):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return original_function(*args, **kwargs)
        except ProblemA as e:
            return Response("Problem A has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
        except ProblemB as e:
            return Response("Problem B has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
        except ProblemC as e:
            return Response("Problem C has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)
        except ProblemD as e:
            return Response("Problem D has occurred, try this to fix it.", status=400)

    return decorated

# twice this - note the @decorator matching the above function.
@catch_all_those_pesky_exceptions
def post(request):
    return backend_function(request.post)
```

Now I can add more exception-handling in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself repeating code, encapsulate it in a function.  In this case, create a function that handles the exception for you.

```
def try_find_field(field_name, datum, default_value):
    try:
        return find_field(field_name, datum)[0]
    except:
        return default_value
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
def exception_handler(exception_class):
    logger = logging.getLogger('app_error')
    logger.error(exception_class)

    exception_name = exception_class.__name__

    if exception_name == 'AuthenticationError':
        raise AuthenticationError
    elif exception_name == 'AuthorizationError':
        raise AuthorizationError
    elif exception_name == 'ConnectionError':
        raise ConnectionError
    else:
        raise GenericError

def call_external_api()
    try:
        result = http_request()
    except Exception as e:
        exception_handler(exception_class=type(e))
```

Comment: The problem of using `type(e)` to determine an exception class is that it won't work with its sub-classes, so for example any subclass of `ConnectionError` would raise a `GenericError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of `except` blocks over and over, handling different kinds of exceptions. There's also nothing wrong with having multiple statements in the same try/catch block.

```
try:
    doMyDangerousThing()
except ValueError:
    print "ValueError!"
except HurrDurrError:
    print "hurr durr, there's an error"

try:
    doMyDangerousThing()
    doMySecondDangerousThing()
except:
    print "Something went wrong!"
```

Comment: While I am appreciative of your feedback, I feel this answer misses the entire point of the question. I do not have a need to handle different exceptions differently (in fact any error produces a blank), but instead asked how I could clean up code in which there were a series of nearly identical try-except blocks.